# Unexpected Java Functional Interface conversion

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

I have the following piece of code, that uses java Functional Interfaces, that compiles, but it's not clear why does it compile:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final RecordIterator it = new RecordIterator<MyRecord>();

        final UpdateManager updateManager = new UpdateManager();
        updateManager.doUpdateForEach(it, DatabaseOperator::updateInfo);

    }
}

class UpdateManager {

    public void doUpdateForEach(final RecordIterator recordIterator,
                                final FunctionalStuff<MyRecord> updateAction) throws Exception {

        updateAction.execute(new DatabaseOperator(), new MyRecord());

    }

}

class RecordIterator<E> {

}

@FunctionalInterface
interface FunctionalStuff<T> {

    void execute(final DatabaseOperator database, final T iterator) throws Exception;

}

class DatabaseOperator {

    public void updateInfo(final MyRecord r) {

    }

}

class MyRecord {

}
```

So, my confusion is inside of the `main` method:

- the last line of the main method is `updateManager.doUpdateForEach(it, DatabaseOperator::updateInfo);`
- the `UpdateManager#doUpdateForEach` method expects a `RecordIterator` (ok, makes sense), and a `FunctionalStuff`
- `FunctionalStuff` has a single method (obviously), that receives 2 params
- The second argument of the `doUpdateForEach` is a method reference (`DatabaseOperator::updateInfo`)
- The `DatabaseOperator::updateInfo` method receives a single argument

how does this compiles? How is the `DatabaseOperator::updateInfo` method reference converted into the functional interface? Am I missing something obvious? Or is some corner case of functional interfaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How is the `DatabaseOperator::updateInfo` method reference converted
>   into the functional interface?

The effective lambda representation of your method reference is :

```
updateManager.doUpdateForEach(it, (databaseOperator, r) -> databaseOperator.updateInfo(r));
```

which is further representation of anonymous class:

```
new FunctionalStuff<MyRecord>() {
    @Override
    public void execute(DatabaseOperator databaseOperator, MyRecord r) throws Exception {
        databaseOperator.updateInfo(r);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `FunctionalStuff<T>` is defined like that:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface FunctionalStuff<T> {
    void execute(final DatabaseOperator database, final T iterator) throws Exception;
}
```

The method reference `DatabaseOperator::updateInfo` is converted to an instance of `FunctionalStuff<MyRecord>` like that (I left the actual types for clearification, but they can be omitted):

```
FunctionalStuff<MyRecord> func = (DatabaseOperator database, MyRecord r) -> database.updateInfo(r);
```

Or if you want to use it as an anonymous class:

```
FunctionalStuff<MyRecord> func = new FunctionalStuff<MyRecord>() {
    void execute(final DatabaseOperator database, final MyRecord r) {
        database.updateInfo(r);
    }
}
```

See the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) with the following example:

> **Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type**
>
> The following is an example of a reference to an instance method of an
>   arbitrary object of a particular type:
>
> ```
> String[] stringArray = { "Barbara", "James", "Mary", "John",
>     "Patricia", "Robert", "Michael", "Linda" };
> Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
> ```
>
> The equivalent lambda expression for the method reference
>   `String::compareToIgnoreCase` would have the formal parameter list
>   `(String a, String b)`, where `a` and `b` are arbitrary names used to
>   better describe this example. The method reference would invoke the
>   method `a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 different types of method reference and you are using [Instance method reference of an object of a particular type](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx#instance-method-reference-of-an-object-of-a-particular-type)

Now at first sight it is similar to `static method reference` which is `Class::staticType` but it has the following difference:

```
- the method should be present in the class same as type of first argument in functional interface
- The method used should have one less argument as opposed to number of arguments in the method declared in functional interface as the **this** reference is taken as first argument.
```

So in your case the method `DatabaseOperator#updateInfo` is present in the `DatabaseOperator` class which is same as the type `DatabaseOperator` of the first argument of `execute` method inside the functional interface and the number of argument in the method is one less as the `this` reference is taken as the first argument.

If you change the DatabaseOperator#updateInfo to take two arguments then compiler will show an error saying `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method updateInfo  from the type DatabaseOperator`. So you can either make the method, to be used as reference, static or you have to use `new DatabaseOperator()#updateInfo` which are two other types of method reference in java.

Answer (score -3):

This is not how lambdas actually work, but essentially you could see

```
updateManager.doUpdateForEach(it, DatabaseOperator::updateInfo);
```

as

```
DatabaseOperator referencedMethodOwner = instanceGivenAsMethodExpression;
updateManager.doUpdateForEach(it, 

    new FunctionalStuff{
        void execute(final T iterator) throws Exception{
            referencedMethodOwner.updateInfo(iterator)
       }
    });
```

Comment: This doesnt compile at all.

Comment: This is not supposed to be compiled.

Comment: It doesnt explain anything. Downvote because your point is unclear.