# How to explain casting method reference to Iterable in for-each loop in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

I found the following code:

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path, charset)) {
    for (String line : (Iterable<String>) lines::iterator) {
        //logic
    }
}
```

This code is compiled and works as expected. However, I can't understand this piece: `(Iterable<String>) lines::iterator`. As I understand a for-each loop is `for (Foo foo: Iterable<Foo> iterable) {}`. But how can method reference be casted to `Iterable`? Could anyone explain?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected Java Functional Interface conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944736/unexpected-java-functional-interface-conversion)

Comment: `lines.forEach(line -> { // logic })` would do the same and maybe slightly easier to understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java converts any method reference or lambda you see to an actual type: That type must be a so-called functional type, which is any interface where, if you take away any methods in `java.lang.Object` and also any methods with a `default` implementation, leaves precisely one method. Then that is a functional interface; you can mark it `@FunctionalInterface` but that's merely compiler-checked documentation: That act does not make it a functional interface; that act merely tells the compiler: Please generate a compiler error if I annotate a thing that is *not* a functional interface with it.

The thing is, `Iterable` **is** a functional interface: it is an interface that defines one method, with the signature: Given zero arguments, produce 1 Iterator.

And, turns out, `lines::iterator` **also** fits that signature: That is a method that takes no arguments, and returns one iterator.

Note that `lines::iterator` does not invoke the iterator() method of whatever `lines` is. Instead it encodes the idea of doing that. The value of `lines::iterator` is 'the idea of invoking the iterator() method on whatever `lines` is'. Whatever code is given 'this concept' can then choose to actually go ahead and do that. And then do it again. Or never do it. Or save it and do it tomorrow, in another thread.

That is, if it compiles at all - that is a method ref, so it **must** be used in a context where a functional type is required; you can't just write `Object o = lines::iterator;`.

Given the cast, there is now a context. So, that's fine then. `(Iterable<String>) lines::iterator` is valid java.

It even does the key semantic difference between `Iterable` and `Iterator`: Iterable is repeatable: You can 'start over' - just invoke the `.iterator()` method a second time which gets you a fresh new iterator that starts at the beginning. In contrast, an `Iterator` cannot go back. Once you invoke `next()` you have moved on. There is no `prev()` or `reset()` or `goTo(0)` or whatnot. You can invoke `.iterator()` on this `Iterable<String>` you have created more than once and the compiler won't stop you from writing that code.

Except, that's not actually useful: **So this is a hack** but a relatively innocuous one. `Iterable` instances are meant to be repeatable, but the docs of `Stream`'s `iterator()` method is quite clear that it is not repeatable - once you walk through that iterator you can't do it again. The compiler won't complain if you invoke `.iterator()` more than once, but the runtime will - that second call will cause an exception. That's *why* `Stream` has an `iterator()` method, but *does not* implement `Iterable<T>`. Even though it trivially could - the compiler wouldn't stop Stream from doing that (as all instances of Iterable must have a method: `public Iterator<T> iterator()`, which.. `Stream<T>` does!. Not every requirement in an API can be captured by the type system, and 'must be invokable multiple times, returning a fresh, functioning iterator positioned at the start of whatever this is, every time you call it' **is** a thing Iterables should do, but which this *does not*, and which the type system cannot capture.

Hence, this **produces a broken Iterable**. So, letting it escape as part of a public api is a very very bad idea. However, in this snippet, it is used immediately so presumably the code can 'work around' the brokenness of it (the brokenness being: You can't invoke `iterator()` on it more than just the one time). The code really should have a comment explaining that this is a half-arsed iterable and therefore the code must not allow it to escape, nor can this code invoke `iterator()` on it more than once.